# cant toggle my navigation bar over media quires, looking for a solution.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I created the following navigation bar on my website, i followed many tutorials over the web in the past few days looking for a way to solve my toggle issue on the responsive side of my navbar, I look for a solution to toggle back my navigation after the media queries takes effect. look for a way that the "☰" opens the menu, I usually use pure CSS because I'm not really good with JS. thanks a lot. both the CSS and the HTML codes are in here.

```css
nav {
width:100%;
margin-top: 0;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-family: arial;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
position:fixed;

text-align:right;
z-index:10;


}

nav li{
    display: inline;
 
}
nav ul{
min-height:20px;

}
.navi{
background: rgba(0,0, 0, 0.5);


}
.navi:hover{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
}

.link-1 {
transition: 0.3s ease;
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
border-top: 1px solid ;
text-align:right;
padding: 20px 0px;
margin: 0 20px;
font-weight: italic;
letter-spacing:2px;
}
.link-1:hover {
border-top: 2px solid #fff;

text-decoration: none;
color:#fff;

padding: 3px 6px;

}


.logo{
text-align:left;
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:-25px;
}



/*media try*/

@media (max-width: 580px) {


nav {
width:100%;
margin-top: 0;
display:block;
max-height:0;
margin-top:-20px;
padding-top:18px;
}

nav li{
display:block;
padding:10px;

}
.navi{
background: rgba(0,0, 0, 0.9);
text-align:center;
border:0;

}
.navi:hover{
background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
border:0;
}

.link-1 {
border:0px solid #bbb;
font-size:18px;

}
.link-1:hover {
text-decoration:underline;
border:0px solid #bbb;

}


.logo{
text-align:left;
margin-left:35px;
margin-top:-25px;
    display: none;
}



}
```

```html
<nav class="navi" id="target">
 <div class="menu">

  <li><a class="link-1" href="#">main</a></li>
  <li><a class="link-1" href="#">second</a></li>
  <li><a class="link-1" href="#">third</a></li>
  <div class="logo">
  <li><a href="#"><img alt="Brand" src="logo.png" height="40px" width="60px"></a><li>
  </div>

 <div class="handle">☰</div>
 </div>

 </nav>
```

Comment: Can you clarify for me what you are trying to do. It seems like you are trying to toggle the menu when a user clicks on the handle. Is that correct?

Comment: Thanks for adding the snippet and the code, but can you please clarify your request about the way you want the menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First what you are going to want to do is include Jquery into your site, so throw this little snippet into your footer right before your END body tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, you are going to want to use a VERY simple toggle script to show your navigation class .menu like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $(".handle").click(function(){
            $(".menu").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Put that right after the jQuery which I mentioned above.

Now, add these two lines of CSS to your styles inside the Media Query:

```
.menu {display:none;}
.handle {display:block;}
```

And then add these two to the normal styles outside the media query to hide your mobile icon on desktop view:

```
.menu {display:block;}
.handle {display:none;}
```

SO. with that said, you can feel free to adjust CSS a little, but those main points above I gave you, are a very good starting point for you I hope.

[You can see a Working Example of your code here at my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/2m41acwp/)

[Here is another version](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/2m41acwp/11/), with an identical "mobile_menu" which is hidden on desktop, and only shows during mobile toggle. It also allows the menu to show after resizing as well.

Hope that helps!
Michael G

Comment: thanks alot it was much helpful though it dosent seem to get 100% width, any ideas? after close the div and enlarge the browser back it disappear.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of Mobile Menu meant to be displayed on Mobile? Not to be rude, but if you are on mobile, you will never have the option to resize the navigation, so it shouldn't matter. Let me see if i can help you find a solution though, just in case I guess.

Comment: honestly this is the least of my problems, my bigger issue is with that the width isn't get full width. i want it to cover an 100% width. and currently it doesn't, and it looks like nobs.